# error: expected ')' before '*' token in header

Tags: c++

I am making a program where there is a Hero who has a Sword. I have a class for both of those. In the header I get the error: `expected ')' before '*' token` on the line `Sword(Hero* h);` in the header of Sword. Here is the compete file (Sword.h):

```
#ifndef SWORD_H
#define SWORD_H

#include <Hero.h>

class Sword {
    public:
        Sword(Hero* h);
        virtual ~Sword();
};

#endif // SWORD_H
```

Hero.h is in the same directory as Hero.h, and I'm using Code::Blocks.

I've looked through other posts and couldn't find anything that helped, so any given would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is the content of Hero.h:

```
#ifndef HERO_H
#define HERO_H

#include <string>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <Sword.h>
#include <Sprite.h>
#include <Window.h>

class Hero : public Sprite {
    public:
        Hero(Window* w);
        void update();
        void event(SDL_Event e);
        ~Hero();
    protected:
    private:
        bool up;
        bool right;
        bool left;
        bool down;

        Window* window;
        Sword* sword;
};

#endif // HERO_H
```

Comment: How is `Hero` defined? Btw you should use `"…"` to include files from the same project and `<…>` only for external files.

Comment: Woah... In sword.h you are using Hero.h and then in Hero.h you are using sword.h

Comment: `Hero* sword;` something seems to be wrong here…

Comment: @zenith yeah, must not have been thinking... but that still didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot include Sword.h from Hero.h and Hero.h from Sword.h, the inclusion chain has to stop somewhere. You can use a **forward declaration** to fix it:

```
//#include <Hero.h> // remove this

class Hero; // forward declaration

class Sword {
    public:
        Sword(Hero* h);
        virtual ~Sword();
};
```

This works because you don't need the definition of `Hero` in Sword.h. The compiler only needs to know that `Hero` is a `class`.

You can do the same in Hero.h: replace `#include <Sword.h>` with `class Sword;`. You can then include the files in the corresponding .cpp files where you need the definitions in order to use the classes.

**Rule of thumb**: always use forward declaration, unless the whole header *needs* to be included.

Further reading: [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/553682/3425536)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a circular dependency. You can fix it with forward declarations:

```
class Hero; //in Sword.h, before defining Sword

class Sword; //in Hero.h, before defining Hero
```